# Custom button with text on RadioButton

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I need to dynamically change the text in the drawable of a RadioButton. It should look something like this

[image]

Where the `A` should be able to change.

My first thought was to set a shape-drawable background to a TextView (to get the border around the `A`) and use that layout in the RadioButton. But I haven't found a way to do that. All I can find is to set drawables/shapes/selectors to a RadioButton, not to set an actual TextView layout.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: you will likely have to create your own custom view

Comment: Indeed. I'm trying but doesn't get it to work, so I turned to here :).

Comment: without a custom view, you can do it. Keep a framelayout and take two child in it one is radio button with custom background and other is TextView aligned to center. You can look for Framelayout examples also.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: Turns out I solved it with a ListView instead. I just keep track of the current pressed view and update the items accordingly. I'll leave this question open if someone cracks a RadioButton solution.